# URL fragment (#) allowed characters

Tags: url, fragment-identifier

After some digging on the internet I was unable to find a good answer to which characters I may use for URL fragment. I'm writing a javascript-script that will take advantage of URL fragments.

I wanted to make the URL eye-friendly by not having it looking too complicated. So I was wondering if I could use characters like ':, ?, & or !' in the URL fragment and still have it valid.

My URL fragment should contain the following values:

- **order-by**

  - **id**
  - **desc** or **asc**
- **path**

  - **/the/full/escaped/path/here/**

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: Thank you bmargulies, but I'm still unable to find the valid characters for URL fragment on that page.

Comment: See 2.5 and 3.5. The later ends by saying that anything, even / and ?, can occur.

Comment: To me it only says that characters / and ? are allowed. (The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to
   represent data within the fragment identifier.)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### tl;dr

The fragment identifier component can contain:

- `0` - `9`
- `a` - `z`
- `A` - `Z`
- `?` `/` `:` `@` `-` `.` `_` `~` `!` `$` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `;` `=`
- percent-encoded characters (a `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits)

### How can I find this out?

The URI standard is [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which currently maps to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

In this document, you’ll find everything you need to know.

The [*fragment identifier component* is defined in section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> `fragment = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )`

This means that the fragment can contain nothing or (any combination of)

- characters defined in *pchar*
- [the `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441627/1591669)
- the `?`

#### Definition of `pchar`

Refer to the [appendix A.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) to see how *pchar* is defined:

> `pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`

So this adds

- characters defined in *unreserved*
- characters defined in *pct-encoded*
- characters defined in *sub-delims*
- the `:`
- [the `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/1591669)

#### Definition of `unreserved`

Now check how *unreserved* is defined:

> `unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`

This adds

- characters defined in *ALPHA*
- characters defined in *DIGIT*
- the `-`
- the `.`
- the `_`
- the `~`

#### Definition of `ALPHA` and `DIGIT`

Check how ALPHA and DIGIT are defined. They are not listed in the appendix, because they are from the [core ABNF rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234#section-6.1), as is [explained in section 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.3):

> ALPHA (letters), […] DIGIT (decimal digits) […]

So this adds

- `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`
- `0`-`9`

#### Definition of `pct-encoded`

Check how *pct-encoded* is defined:

> `pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG`

This allows for any [percent-encoded character](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

#### Definition of `sub-delims`

Check how *sub-delims* is defined:

> `sub-delims = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="`

This adds

- the `!`
- the `$`
- the `&`
- the `'`
- the `(`
- the `)`
- the `*`
- the `+`
- the `,`
- the `;`
- the `=`

Comment: A regex for valid characters in the fragment identifier component would be very useful here :-) Can anyone provide this?

Comment: `^([-?/:@._~!$&'()*+,;=a-zA-Z0-9]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*$` (Some escaping might be required depending on your regex dialect.)

Comment: i noticed that "#" isn't listed as being valid in a fragment, although it seems browsers are lenient at allowing multiple ones of them...

Comment: Note that when using ":" in IDs, you need to escape it when using `querySelector` as `\\:`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky to find the valid characters, but the file commented above does contain the information if you read deep enough.

The available characters are as follow:

- "!"
- "$"
- "&"
- "'"
- "("
- ")"
- "*"
- "+"
- ","
- ";"
- "="
- "?"
- "@"
- ALPHA
- DIGIT
- "-"
- "."
- "_"
- "~"
- "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
- ":"
- "/"