# What are the eligible characters in a URL's Fragment (location.hash)?

Tags: url, web, unicode, iri

Context: I am creating an app that stores its data in the location.hash. I want to encode as few characters as possible to maintain maximum legibility.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948396/3274693), reserved characters are different for each segment of the URL. So what are the limitations for URL Fragment/location.hash specifically?

Related post:
[Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852/3274693)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?rq=1

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I am targeting modern browsers and it is not an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL fragment (#) allowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088849/url-fragment-allowed-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

```
fragment      = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Unpacking all that, and ignoring percent-encoding, I find the following set of characters:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/?
```

Although the RFC [does not mandate a particular encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) and deals in characters only (not bytes), according to [Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) `ALPHA` means ASCII only, i.e. the 26 letters of the Latin alphabet. Any non-ASCII letters must therefore be percent-encoded.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for your well-referenced answer. I see a lot of web apps using url hash for routing, and in some cases, I see local specific characters (e.g. Persian, Arabic) appearing on the address bar. Is it Chrome displaying them in a human-readable format? if not what is logic behind it?

Comment: I have added my interpretation of the RFC into the post. Yet, using non-ASCII characters seems to work fine in Chrome. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls).