# How to point to an anchor when the fragment identifier is already used in the URL?

Tags: html, url, browser

I have a page (over which I have no control) with an URL similar to

```
https://example.com/#group:1106/about:Bxk9H9jJQOm-pYkmpZVjhA
```

Within this page, there is an element

```
<h1 id="content-H1-59520">Introduction</h1>
```

[Fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (`#`) can be used to point to a specific `id` on a page:

> In URIs for MIME `text/html` pages such as
>   `http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar` the fragment refers to the element
>   with `id="bar"`.

**My question**: taken into account that the fragment identifier is already used in the bare URL, how should I modify it to have it pointing to the `H1` element above?

On a hunch I tried `https://example.com/#group:1106/about:Bxk9H9jJQOm-pYkmpZVjhA#content-H1-59520` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The [fragment identifier component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) is indicated by **the first `#`** and terminated by the end of the URL. The URL you tested is invalid, because the fragment identifier component [may not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119120/1591669) a `#`.

The URL has to be:

```
https://example.com/#content-H1-59520
```

If a JavaScript-based site requires the fragment identifier to [represent application states](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/IdentifyingApplicationState), it conflicts with the browser feature to jump to an ID.

You could either switch to a different URI design (that doesn’t require the fragment identifier component), or maybe you could rebuild the jump feature in JavaScript (e.g., appending the anchor ID to the fragment, delimited by `@`).